# To state something to be a reason or as a reason

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, prepositions

I'm writing a critical review. I have written the following sentence. I would like to know if there is some significant problems. Especially I have a problem with the expression "stated to be a reason in order to". Could it be "stated as a reason"? Or some other way? And could it be "reason for"?

"Thus, while an objective, which in itself is legitimate, would has been stated to be a reason in order to override a right, the restriction may nevertheless be in fact motivated by hidden or unacceptable reasons, in which case the stated reason is just the pretext."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the expression "stated to be a reason in order to" the "in order to" would refer not to the "reason", but to "stated to". In other words it would mean that something was stated as a reason for something entirely else in order to signify something. "As a reason for" would imply that an event happened and whatever preceded "as a reason for" was the reason for that event.

To put it in the context of your presented sentence, the legitimate objective was stated as reason so that someone can override a right. However if you write "..., was stated as a reason for overriding a right" you would imply that because of this legitimate objective a right has been overridden.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is illustrative. Would "as a reason to override a right" work then?

Comment: Yes you could write that something was stated as a reason to override a right.